# How to list applicants who applied to my job listing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users who create job listings as well as apply to job listings.

**Jobs Table**
When a user creates a job listing, it looks like this:

```
=> #<Job id: 9, created_at: "2021-04-30 11:30:41", updated_at: "2021-04-30 11:30:41", job_title: "Healer", job_description: "Magical Healer Needed", job_price: 20000, user_id: 3, photo: nil, job_long_description: "Help me get better cause I dont feel good", job_location: "London">
```

**Jobapps Table**
When a user applies for a job, it looks like this:

```
=> #<Jobapp id: 7, created_at: "2021-04-30 14:13:38", updated_at: "2021-04-30 14:13:38", user_id: 6, job_id: 9, message: "I have magical space drugs that will blow your min...">
```

Note the matching job_ids above...

**THE PROBLEM**
I want the job poster to see a list of of people who have applied to the job posters listings.

How do I show all job_ids from the JOBAPP table that are associated with the job poster?
Does this need a 'through' association / join table?

For some extra info, please see my database
[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PQWu.png)

---

Thanks for your time, if you need me to post more info (models etc.), please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mentor helped me out and suggested a similar route as SVRourke in the answers above.

We added this to my model(which surprised me)

```
def applicants
    @applicants = []
    self.jobs.each do |job|
      job.jobapps.each do |jobapp|
        hash_jobapp = {job: jobapp.job, user: jobapp.user, jobapp: jobapp}
        @applicants << hash_jobapp
      end
    end
    @applicants
  end
```

Then we linked the logic from model to the relevant controller

```
def applicant
    @applicants = current_user.applicants
end
```

Then in your views, you can call each column from the appropriate table using [:user] [:job] etc.

```
<div class="container-job-index">
    <h1>All Applicants to my jobs</h1>
    <p>All applicants to your jobs should appear here</p>
    <% @applicants.each do |jobapp| %>
    <div class="job-card">
        <div class="job-info">
            <h3 class="job-card-title"><%= jobapp[:user].fname %></h3>
            <p class="job-card-description"><%= jobapp[:job].job_title %></p>
            <p class="">Message: <%= jobapp[:jobapp].message %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> THE PROBLEM I want the job poster to see a list of of people who have applied to the job posters listings.

So for clarification you would essentially want an array of all applications for all job postings of a user across multiple different jobs?

If that's the case i would do a through: relationship like job has_many applicants through jobapps source: user

that way you could call instanceOfAJob.applicants and get an array of users, then you could create a user method that accumulates mappings of your jobs into applicants

if you just want an array of applicant users for a specific job I would just create a method on the job class that uses map and a where clause like

job.jobapps.map { |ja| ja.user }

I'm sorry if i misunderstood your question! you might want to do a reread of the ActiveRecord associations https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: That was the right direction but I have the exact answer now which i will share.